# Erroneous "org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a weird issue with Hibernate: sometimes, when I try to fetch object by ID I get "More than one row with the given identifier was found". I issue the same statement in catch bloc and everything works perfectly.
While this workaround is acceptable in explicit session.get() case, I've started receiving similar errors in case of @ManyToOne dereferencing, where I can't use this workaround.
Here is my code and output listing:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.dooks.ga.HibernateUtil;
import com.mf.model.network.ethernet.h3c.H3cSwitch;

public class StandaloneChassisFetchTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionWithTransaction();

    String id = "A063D7CC-14E5-48F2-974B-20DDE3A981C6";

    H3cSwitch sw;
    try {
        System.err.println("First try");
        sw = (H3cSwitch) session.get(H3cSwitch.class, id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Second try");
        sw = (H3cSwitch) session.get(H3cSwitch.class, id);
    }

    System.err.println("Name :" + sw.getDisplayName());
    System.err.println("Type :" + sw.getClass().getSimpleName());

    HibernateUtil.releaseCommitSession(session);
}
}
```

Output listing

```
First try
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: A063D7CC-14E5-48F2-974B-20DDE3A981C6, for class: com.mf.model.network.ethernet.h3c.StandaloneH3cSwitch
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:104)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3917)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1091)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:174)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2473)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:987)
at com.dooks.testing.StandaloneChassisFetchTest.main(StandaloneChassisFetchTest.java:19)
Second try
Name :HP A7500
Type :StandaloneH3cSwitch
```

Java version : 1.7
 Hibernate version : 4.2.0
 Database : MySQL
 JDBC driver : mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar

I've tried to use Hibernate 5, and got the same issue.

I will appreciate any insight, as I'm totally lost!

Comment: it seems you you really have two distinct rows with the same id or your notion of an identifier for H3cSwitch is different from what you have in the database. Can you post your table and model definitions as well?